# RunningPuppy Animated Gif

Tags: javascript

I am stuck on my homework project. I am supposed to create a JavaScript program that shows an animated puppy running. I must use caching to start the animation as soon as the images finish loading and 1 of the following: `getElementsByName()`, `getElementById()`, or `getElementsByTagName()`. Here's what I have so far but when I run it in Firefox all I see is a flashing box that says "image of a puppy"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Running Puppy</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;
    charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var puppy = new Array(6);
var curPuppy = 0
for (var imagesLoaded=0; imagesLoaded < 6;
    ++imagesLoaded) {
    puppy[imagesLoaded] = new Image();
    puppy[imagesLoaded].src
        = "images/puppy" + imagesLoaded + ".gif";
    }
function run(){
    if (curPuppy == 5)
        curPuppy = 0;
    else
        ++curPuppy;
    document.getElementById("puppyImage").src = puppy[curPuppy].src;
}
/*]]> */
</script>

</head>
<body onload="setInterval('run()', 150)">
<img src="images/puppy0.gif" id="puppyImage" width="263" height="175" alt="Image of a puppy." />

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
document.write("<h1 id='mainHeading'></h1>");
document.getElementById("mainHeading").innerHTML =         document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
/*]]> */
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are your puppy images in the correct directory?  What do they look like?

Comment: Also, are you getting any `console` errors? You will only see the `alt` text if the `img` is not loadable. You sure you have a folder in your `root` called `images` and also a `puppy0.gif` inside of that folder?

Comment: Yes, it is saved in the same folder as the pictures. The picture is a small whitish dog with a few spots on it. There are 6 pictures total. The images are in the "project" folder that we downloaded for the class. That is the same folder that I have this assignment saved to.

Comment: Oh, and no errors and it passes W3C

Comment: You need to set the error handler for your image.